# Get Dynamics 365 Finance & Operations data entity via HTTP GET as CSV output

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365-operations, dynamics-ax7

Given a Finance & Operations environment, the environmentdomain.com/data/EntityName URL allows [OData data retrieval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/odata) in JSON format.

Is there a way to give extra query string parameters to download the results as CSV using HTTP GET only?

A workaround is [described here](https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/f/dynamics-365-for-finance-and-operations-forum/286945/how-to-data-export-csv-file-fomat-in-dynamics-365), however it has more overhead for ad hoc situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [supported features from the OData specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/odata#supported-features-from-the-odata-specification) for the D365FO OData requests do not support the [system query option $format](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part1-protocol.html#_Toc31358963).

So no, as far as I can tell, there is no query string parameter that would return the HTTP GET request response in csv format.

## Additional workarounds

Since the questions mentions a workaround that has some overhead for ad hoc situations, here are two more suggestions how the response can be changed to CSV format with less overhead.

### Postman

[Postman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/third-party-service-test#query-odata-by-using-postman) is often used for ad hoc testing of the D365FO OData API. [Convert a JSON reponse to CSV](https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-answers/collection/9215231-34100f3a-b97d-46ea-a5ba-9d6f59526272?ctx=documentation) describes how a Javascript test can be added to a Postman request to convert the JSON response to CSV format and write it to the console.

### PowerShell

The [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) cmdlet can be used to send HTTP GET requests to the D365FO API. The result can then be used with the [Export-Csv](https://github.com/d365collaborative/d365fo.integrations/blob/development/docs/Get-D365ODataEntityData.md) cmdlet to create a CSV file.

I strongly recommend you use the [d365fo.integrations](https://github.com/d365collaborative/d365fo.integrations) PowerShell module written by @splaxi specifically to interact with the D365FO OData API instead of `Invoke-RestMethod`. The [Get-D365ODataEntityData](https://github.com/d365collaborative/d365fo.integrations/blob/development/docs/Get-D365ODataEntityData.md) can be used to send an HTTP GET request.